# What is the difference between Authorization filters and Action filters

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What is the exact difference between Authorization filters and Action filters in MVC?

For checking user session or validating user login, for these purposes which one should i use?

I am new to MVC, Please explain rather providing links also it will be helpful if you could give its samples of usage.

Comment: [Refer documetation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(VS.98).aspx) for a detailed explanation

Comment: Ok according to you on which filter should i give user session check?

Comment: i think it depends right?

Comment: You would use a `Authorization` filter (you would want it to be the first thing you check)

Comment: Ok so once my action executed and for some time site was idle, then again after session timeout if i am calling same action will it trigger Authorization filter?

Comment: If your method is decorated with that attribute, then yes (the attribute will trigger every time you call that method)

Answer (score 1):

Authorization Filter is a specialized filter to check whether a user is authorized to access certain resources, while with action filter you could create custom filter overriding the `OnActionExecuting` , `OnActionExecuted`, `OnResultExecuting` and `OnResultExecuted` method, depends on your purpose. I used Action Filter to check user's session.
Here's a [nice article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs) explaining action filter

For authorization there's a neat library called [fluent security](http://www.fluentsecurity.net/) to implement authorization features, as alternative to the original which I think easier to implement